# didrecieveremotenotfication is not called when app is in push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

I am using push notification in iOS 10.I am using below delegate in my appdelegate class.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("state is )")
  }
```

It gets called when app is in foreground mode.But when app is in background then this method does not get called.Please tell me what is that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Add check Mark Background Fetch EX:
[image]

Comment: will it afftect provisioing profile ?I have sent 1 IPA to client so will it not affect exsting  ipa

Comment: so that IPA sent will get affected ?

Comment: I think you need to first check after that you can sent.

Comment: No i am asking if i change capabilties in my app here so will that IPA sent get affected ?

Comment: If you change capabilities in your app. after that run  on iPhone check you . it will affect.